# How to do "begins with" query with a MarkLogic cts:query()

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am accessing a MarkLogic database (v 8.0-3) using structured queries through the REST API. I cannot figure out how to configure the indexes to do "begins with" queries of a text field. So for example if a company was named "Sunday Sunshine Inc." I'd like to be able find it by searching begins with "sund" (also by contains "sunshine"). A query like - begins with "suns" - should *not* find the company.

For example the following "begins with" query should NOT find the document but it does:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:document-insert("/test/doc",<a>Sunday Sunshine Inc.</a>);
let $term := "suns"
return cts:search(fn:collection(),
          cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("a"),$term || "* *",
         ("wildcarded","unstemmed","case-insensitive")),"unfiltered")
```

I have the following indexes configured:

- word searches
- word positions
- fast phrase searches
- fast case sensitive searches
- fast diacritic sensitive searches
- fast element word searches
- element word positions
- fast element phrase searches
- element value positions
- three character searches
- three character word positions
- fast element character searches
- trailing wildcard searches

Also the following query gets the correct results (e.g. no hits):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:document-insert("/test/doc",<a>Sunday Sunshine Inc.</a>);
let $term := "suns"
return cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("a"),$term || "*",
                                         ("case-insensitive"))
```

but using `cts:element-value-match()` would require a custom constraint query through the rest interface which I'd rather not do. But I think it strange `cts:element-value-match()`, which is unfiltered, works - so the indexes must be there to evaluate the query.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running with `filtered` instead of `unfiltered`? That should help I think. If you prefer unfiltered, you could also consider using a range index and a element-range-query. That won't support wildcards, but you can gt/le kind of operators on strings as well..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. We would really rather use unfiltered - the number of possible responses can be large (millions) and filtering could take a while. We have discussed using a range index, but that is a last resort I think. We can derive the upper range by adding 1 to the codepoint but we'd have to take diacritics and case into account - never mind we' d have add yet another range index ...

Comment: You should be able to work around diacritics and case with collations. Have a look at the collation builder that can be found in the Admin UI when adding any string range index to a database.

Comment: @grtjn Thanks again for the quick response. We have considered using element-range-query() - so if the user typed `suná` we could flatten the diacritic and search `GE suna and LT sunb`  - that said, hopefully there not too many gotchas awaiting when flattening. Still, I am hoping there is a way to do this that "just works"- how does cts:element-value-match() do this?

Comment: value-match uses range indexes, so looks like you have a range index in place already. http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-match

Comment: @grtjn You are correct - I had configured it on a test database as part of playing with this - I didn't realize cts:element-value-match() used the range index. Looks like we'll be using range queries. I might do this by first calling cts:element-value-match() to get the maximum value for the upper range of the range queries in order to avoid dealing with the diacritics - even though that will require a custom constraint. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Compiled these comments into an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composed from above comments:

Query functions like `cts:element-value-query` leverage the so-called universal index. This index is essentially a word lexicon that supports full-text searching in MarkLogic. To search for values, it first tokenizes the value into 'words' to look for fragments containing all required 'words'.

Next, if `element word positions` has been enabled, it can save on filtering by checking the order of the 'words'. Apparently, filtering is not entirely cancelled and still necessary to filter out false positives.

Functions like `cts:element-value-match` are not used together with `cts:search` or related. Moreover, they require a range index, as can be read in the documentation: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-match

Because these match function rely on range indexes, it looks at the value lexicon of the index only. Since that lexicon is built for that particular element, and range values are always matched from start to end of the string, a pattern like `suns*` will not return false positives. Range indexes are also kept in memory for fast access. That is why range indexes are efficient, and need no filtering. They do come at a cost of taking up disk and memory space, and slowing down ingest a little.

Note: collations can be very useful to ignore things like case, diacritics, and white-space. You can read more about this in the search dev guide: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/encodings_collations

The only downside to range queries is that you cannot do wildcard searches on them. It is easy enough, though, to put a call to one of the value-match function inside it, to make it return all relevant values, and effectively do a so-called shotgun-OR on them. You can also take first, and last from a value-match call, and use that to construct a `>= AND <` kind of range query..

HTH!